# PDFBox - ÅÄÖ is missing in rendered image

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox (  2.0.4. ) for converting pdf's to images ( jpg ). It all works great except one thing.

Swedish letters as Å, Ä and Ö are just gone in the image. All other letters works great.

What is going on? I read something about font, that it could cause the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The font doesn't necessarily have those characters. Especially if the font is designed for English usage only.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what version you are using, and if possible share the PDF.

Comment: @Kayaman is it possible to add "Å", "Ä" and "Ö" somehow to the font in the java code? How do i solve this kind of problem?

Comment: No. Fonts are designed by people. You can't magically add things there.

Comment: You need to use a font that includes those letters.

Comment: @Kayaman Ok, so is it possible somehow to use a standard font like "Helvetica" or "Sans-serif" etc..? Somehow tell the pdfbox to use "Helvetica" as font while converting the pdfs to images?

Comment: @Kayaman I think your theory is incorrect because PDFBox doesn't have a call "use that font for rendering  a PDF". But to be sure I need to see the PDF.

Comment: @RobinRyden please include any log messages you get.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Well you're right, the embedded font *should* have those glyphs.

Comment: @RobinRyden is Adobe Reader able to display the file properly? Btw "latest" is not really helpful. I've had a guy claiming that he used the "latest" version and it was 0.7.3 (10 years old). The latest is 2.0.4.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I'm able to read the PDF itself, and then it shows me the letters Å,Ä,Ö.

But the image that was created are missing those letters.

Comment: @RobinRyden Please share the PDF in question and show the code you use for conversion.

Comment: You make it difficult to help you. If you can't see log messages, try looking at the PDF with the PDFDebugger commandline application https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html#pdfdebugger . The log messages appear in a small window if you click on the status line.